# How to add different child components to component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react. I'm trying to create the following structure for a component in react:

```
<Sidebar>
  <Box>
    <Title/>
    <Item/>
    <Item/>
  </Box>
  <Box>
    <Title/>
    <Switch/>
  </Box>
</Sidebar>
```

I can include the Title component in the Box component and pass each title value through props. How do I include the Item component in just the first Box component and not the second?

Is the best way to pass the Item and Switch components into the Box components as props?

Comment: You arleady placed it.Do you want it  dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do what you're asking and really it really depends on where you are going with your program.

- Multiple Types of Box components (with different names)
- Wrap all of you sub-components in a div, and pass that div to your Box's 'children' prop. (Slightly changes your hierarchy).

Example

```
<Box children={<div><Title/><Item/><Item/></div>}/>
<Box children={<div><Title/><Item/></div>}/>
```

Hierarchy

```
<Sidebar>
  <Box>
    <div>
      <Title/>
      <Item/>
      <Item/>
    </div>
  </Box>
  <Box>
    <div>
      <Title/>
      <Switch/>
    </div>
  </Box>
</Sidebar>
```

- More fancy, build your sub-components from an array or other JS object that you pass as a prop and have a function inside 'Box' that reads that array and builds your sub components.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage the special `children` prop in order to render arbitrary children:

- `children` is a default prop passed implicitly to every component
- this `children` prop is automatically populated with any elements contained within the parent component
- instead of using `props.children` you can destructure `props` and use `({ children(, ...otherProps) })` instead

In action:

`Box.js`

```
const Box = ({ children }) => (
  <div className='box'>
    {children}
  </div>
)
```

`Sidebar.js`

```
const Sidebar = ({ children }) => (
  <div className='sidebar'>
    {children}
  </div>
)
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react'

import Sidebar from './path/to/Sidebar'
import Box from './path/to/Box'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    // state or whatever
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Sidebar>
        <Box>
          {/* 
            Anything you put in here (other components 
            included) will be automatically rendered
          */}
        </Box>
        <Box>
          {/* Same here */}
        </Box>
      </Sidebar>
    )
  }
}
```